# android - create json object from string to handle network errors

Tags: java, android, json

I need create json object to handle network calls errors

the way I parse error

```
{error:errorMessage}
```

my tries :

```
 String error = "{\"error\":\""+ e.getMessage()+"\"}";
```

but when I convert the  `jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());`

it throw exception

my code

```
public class HttpBackground implements Runnable {
        HttpDefs client;
        String error = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject;

        public HttpBackground(HttpDefs client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) client._url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod(client.Request_type);
                connection.setReadTimeout(AppStaticMembers.WAIT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT);

                OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getQuery(client.params));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                outputStream.close();
                connection.connect();
                if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                } else {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
                }
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }


            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                error = "{\"error\":\""+ e.getMessage()+"\"}";

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                error = "{\"error\":\""+ e.getMessage()+"\"}";
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {

                    try {
                        reader.close();


                        stringBuilder.append(error);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            httpUI httpUI = new httpUI(jsonObject, this.client);
            handler.post(httpUI);
        }

    }
```

Comment: post the stack trace of the exception, also you should escape/remove any double quotes in the error message  e.g. e.getMessage().replace("\"", "");

Comment: Instead of trying to manually recreate the JSON format, you could just use the `.append(String key, String val)` method to append the error codes to the object. It prevents you from having string complications in the first place.

Comment: @ConorRoche this is the right answer , post it to accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have

```
String error = "{\"error\":\""+ e.getMessage()+"\"}";
```

you should escape/remove any double quotes in the error message e.g.

```
String escapedError = e.getMessage().replace("\"", "");
String error = "{\"error\":\""+ escapedError +"\"}";
```